# fxLayoutGap return unexpectable react while using angular with angular-flex

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

I am using @angular/flex-layout "^7.0.0-beta.24" with angular 7.0.4 and angular-material 7.1.1.
The code I am using is:

```
<div fxLayout="column">
  <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="13px">
    <div fxFlex>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I expect to see some margin around second element, however it is not working.

If I change it for the following code:

```
<div>
  <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutGap="16px grid">
    <div fxFlex>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

then I am getting something absolutely wrong like in the attached picture. 
Is it a problem with versions or something else?[image]

Comment: Can you please share your template with the `text`, `heading` and `button`? Also can you be more specific aboutwhat you mean by "second element" in first template?

Comment: I also found this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fxhidegap but here it is not working as well

Comment: The second element is  <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="13px"> Please, look also at the link. It use a same code and if you check in the inspect it is not working as well

Comment: for your first query, second element will have a gap only when there is a element next to it, and since in your example (and in the one you have shared as a link) you have no other element inside the parent div, it is not showing any gap. Try adding a div (or any other child).

Comment: I have an element next to it (I didn't add it in the code but it is there). Anyway, even in the code there is a third child element <div fxFlex>. Please, look also at the link in my comment. It is not working there as well @shaktimaan

Comment: If you use `*ngIf="hideBox"` instead of `[fxHide]="hideBox"`, it works fine.